# Unable to locate and click on li element within ul list

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, findelement

I'm trying to click on an li element in a ul dropdown list. I want to select "Last Month" but get this error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Here's my code:

```
def click_on(xpath):
    timeout = time.time() + 30
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).click()
            break
        except Exception:
            if time.time() > timeout:
                msgbox('Process timed out after 30 seconds.', 'Error')
                exit()

click_on('//*[@id="popover_otrppv916b"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[9]/div/span')
```

Here's the html:

[image: html]

I've also tried clicking on just the `<div>` tag, and just the `<li>` tag (instead of the `<span>` tag) and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *id* attribute values like *`popover_otrppv916b`* are dynamically generated and is bound to change sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

To click on the ***clickable*** element with text as ***Last month*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *`normalizespace()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='group-list']//li//span[normalizespace()='Last month']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='group-list']//li//span[contains(., 'Last month')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: This works great. I'm wondering how you knew which XPATH string to use. When I inspect the html of the wepage and copy the XPATH of the button I want to click on, it gave me the one with popover_otrppv916b. How did you know to use "//ul[@class='group-list']//li//span[contains(., 'Last month')]"?